# problema php con formulario de contacto

Tags: php

Os comento el problema y si alguien puede orientarme estaría muy agradecido.
Tengo una página con varios archivos php, en algunos archivos tengo un formulario de contacto (todos con el mismo id="nombre"), el caso es que cuando intento mandar un correo no me lo manda y me deja en la pagina de validación del formulario sin redirigirme a la página de que se ha realizado el contacto con éxito.
Lo he probado en otras páginas(pero solo tienen un formulario) y funciona correctamente, cuando miro el error en Console me aparece esto (y no entiendo error):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si al tener varios formularios con los mismo id entra en conflicto y por eso no lo manda, estuve mirando ayer un error que investigando me decía que podía ser del dns o la caché, no se si lo solucioné pero el error en concreto no aparece.

Os comparto el código, aunque no se si está ahí el problema como comento en otras páginas me funciona:

```
    if(isset($_POST['Email'])) { 
    $email_to = "micorreo@gmail.com"; 
    $email_subject = "Contacto desde mi pagina";
 
    function died($error) { 
        // mensajes de error
        header ("../erroneoContacto.php");        
        die();
    } 
    // Se valida que los campos del formulairo estén llenos 
    if(!isset($_POST['Name']) || 
       !isset($_POST['Email']) || 
        !isset($_POST['Message'])) { 
        die('Por Favor Rellene todos los campos.'); 
    }
 //En esta parte el valor "name"  sirve para crear las variables que recolectaran la información de cada campo 
    $first_name = $_POST['Name']; // requerido 
    $email_from = $_POST['Email']; // requerido 
    $telephone = $_POST['Subject']; // no requerido 
    $message = $_POST['Message']; // requerido 
    $error_message = ""; 
  if(strlen($message) < 2) { 
    $error_message .= 'El formato del texto no es válido.<br />'; 
  } 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { 
    header("location: ../erroneoContacto.php");
    die; 
  } 
//Este es el cuerpo del mensaje tal y como llegará al correo 
    $email_message = "Información desde mipagina.\n\n"; 
    function clean_string($string) { 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string); 
    } 
    $email_message .= "Nombre: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";    
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n"; 
    $email_message .= "Asunto: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n"; 
    $email_message .= "Mensaje: ".clean_string($message)."\n"; 
//Se crean los encabezados del correo 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
// Mensaje de que fue enviado
 header ("location:../exitoContacto.php");
}
?>
```

Gracias a todos, saludos

Comment: Los errores 404 se refieren a recursos no encontrados. ¿Sabes a qué se refiere esa URL del mensaje de error, por lo demás tan extraña? Parece ser una extensión de Chrome.

Comment: No se a que se refiere esa URL, cuando le doy para que me aparezca en una ventana me dice "no se ha podido acceder al archivo".

Comment: Parece ser una extensión de Chrome. Revisa las extensiones que tienes instaladas. Y en cuanto a tu código en sí intenta probar en otro navegador.

Comment: Gracias compañero, tenía un error en el html, la el atributo name del input lo tenía mal, pensaba que en el formulario los datos los cogía por el id, no sabía que el name tenía que estar igual.

Answer (score 0):

Cierro el hilo, tenía un error en el html, la etiqueta name no estaba bien escrita, pensaba que en el formulario solo utilizaba los id, pero en name también pinta algo.
Gracias a todos.